# How do I update one value within an object using setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have an element that contains an attribute called "sound". The value of this sound attribute is an object. One of the properties in this object is "volume".

In other words:

```
<a-entity position='0 0 0' sound='src: url; on: click; volume: 2.0;'></a-entity>
```

So it's like this:

```
{
  position: '0 0 0',
  sound: {
    src: 'url',
    on: 'click',
    volume: '2.0'
  }
}
```

I'm using setAttribute to update the volume attribute but I don't know if there's an effective way to only target one property while not changing the other properties in the object.

Basically this replaces the sound object and removes all the properties that are not specified (src AND on properties are removed):

```
element.setAttribute('sound', {
  volume: '4'
});
```

I don't want to replace the entire object. I only want to replace one value for one property. Is there a best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the 3-argument version of setAttribute which is in the docs here: https://aframe.io/docs/core/entity.html#Updating-Multi-Property-Component-Data

Specifically you can do something like:

```
element.setAttribute("sound", "volume", "4");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could get object corresponding to the attribute, and replace only the properties you need.

Something like this:

```
var data = element.getAttribute('sound');
data.volume = '4';
element.setAttribute('sound', data);
```

**Edit**

If you set the data in the html like a real JS object, you could do:

```
var newData = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('sound'));
newData.volume = 4;
element.setAttribute('sound', JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/dscej6u2/)

Comment: `getAttribute` returns a string, not an object so this won't work

Comment: you could use JSON.parse to parse the string into an object. But I see that your sound attribute data in the HTML it's not really an object as you specified..