# Changing only 1 property of aframe component

Tags: aframe

So I am looking at the docs for aframe regarding component update

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('visible', {
  /**
   * this.el is the entity element.
   * this.el.object3D is the three.js object of the entity.
   * this.data is the component's property or properties.
   */
  update: function (oldData) {
    this.el.object3D.visible = this.data;
  }
  // ...
});
```

How would I use this to change only 1 property while keeping the rest the same? i.e. change value of x, but keep y and z. When I use setAttribute, it seems the properties are just replaced with whatever I passed into setAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the Entity portion of the docs
https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/entity.html#setattribute-attr-value-componentattrvalue after I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568225/how-do-i-update-one-value-within-an-object-using-setattribute?rq=1)!